# Not condition with contains function in xpath for scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am using xpath in scrapy to parse the data and I have some HTML code like given below.

```
<tr>
 <td>RAM</td><td>4 GB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>RAM Frequency</td><td>1600 MHz</td>
</tr>
```

I want to grab the RAM size
Currently I am using the syntax

```
for tr in response.xpath(".//tr[contains(.,'RAM')]"):
    result=tr.xpath(".//td[contains(.//text(),'RAM')]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()").extract()
```

but at the end I am getting 1600 MHz instead of 4 GB. So, My question is, does there exist some syntax like

```
for tr in response.xpath(".//tr[contains(.,'RAM') & not(contains(.,'RAM Frequency'))]")
```

which will parse only RAM not RAM frequency.

Comment: You can use firebug to get the xpath of the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: `.//tr[contains(.,'RAM') and not(contains(.,'RAM Frequency'))]`

#### Read more:

[XPath Reference - Boolean Functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans)